# JMeter POST returns 415 - Unsupported Media Type

Tags: rest, jmeter

Well it's one step forward and two steps back for me. Thanks to you guys, I finally got the GET for my webservice working in JMeter. Now I'm trying a POST, and once again I'm not getting anywhere.

I'm  using a HTTP Request and made the POST body as small as possible: `<the_tag></the_tag>`.
I even took the xml out and just used text.
No matter what's in the body, I get the 415 error.
What am I missing?
My implementation is HC3, protocol https, and I don't have anything else selected (other than the POST, of course). I also set the Content-Type to text/xml.

P.S. I should add that this POST works fine in SoapUI, so I don't think it's a server issue.

Comment: Check this...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032753/jmeter-how-to-send-request-with-content-type-header

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Did you check the content type of your request ?

What is it ? What should it be ?
To set it, add a header manager as child of your sampler and set :

- content-type in column 1
- application/xml in column 2

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Answer (score 6):

Do not forget header manager, and there:

[image]